# Verifying $\frac{\cot\theta-1}{\cot\theta+3}=\frac{\csc^2\theta-6\cot\theta+4}{\csc^2\theta-2\cot\theta-16}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I need to verify the following identity:

$$\dfrac{\cot(\theta) - 1}{\cot(\theta) + 3} = \dfrac{\csc^2(\theta) - 6 \cot(\theta) + 4}{\csc^2(\theta) - 2 \cot(\theta) - 16}$$

using only the    [Pythagorean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_trigonometric_identity) identities. **I'm not allowed to modify the other side in any way** (if I pick the left, I can't change the right, and vice versa), which means I can't just cross-multiply and simplify to verify that both sides are equal.

I've tried to convert the cotangents and cosecants to sines and cosines:

$$\dfrac{\cot(\theta) - 1}{\cot(\theta) + 3} = \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{\sin^2(\theta)} - \dfrac{6 \cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} + 4}{\dfrac{1}{\sin^2(\theta)} - \dfrac{2 \cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} - 16}$$

but I don't see anywhere I could simplify by applying the reciprocal or Pythagorean identities. Is this even the right step towards proving this identity?

I notice that the right side is pretty close to this variation of the Pythagorean identities:

$$ \csc^2(\theta) - \cot^2(\theta) = 1 $$

but I can't use it because the cotangent is not squared. I'm guessing that the solution would use this in some way?

I know this is true since they have the same graph (and Wolfram Alpha agrees).

Comment: Hint: cosecant is squared so you can and should use that Pythagorean identity. Starting from the right,
\begin{align}
\frac{\csc^2\theta-6\cot\theta+4}{\csc^2\theta-2\cot\theta-16}&=
\frac{(1+\cot^2\theta)-6\cot\theta+4}{(1+\cot^2\theta)-2\cot\theta-16}
=\frac{\cot^2\theta-6\cot\theta+5}{\cot^2\theta-2\cot\theta-15}
\end{align}
Notice you have quadratic expressions in terms of $\cot\theta$ in the numerator and denominator. Can you factor them?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks a lot! I believe I can solve it on my own now. I had not thought about expanding $csc^2(\theta)$ before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using slightly modified identity that you mentioned: $ \csc^2(\theta)=1+\cot^2(\theta) $ you can rewrite the RHS as

$$\frac{\cot ^2 \theta - 6\cot \theta+5}{\cot ^2 \theta - 2\cot \theta-15}=\frac{(\cot \theta - 1)(\cot \theta-5)}{(\cot \theta +3)(\cot \theta-5)}$$